# Load random html page Express.js

Tags: javascript, html, express

Nimit this side, need some help with my code.
So can I load different html pages on the same url
eg: www.xyz.com/home/random
can random more than 1 html page

task1.js sim. I have task2.js,task3.js,task4.js only with change in html file name.

```
//This is the root path!
const path = require("path");
const rootDir = require("../utils/path");

//express routing
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.use("/random", (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir, "views", "task_1.html"));
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

const homeRouter = require("./routes/homeRouter");
const taskRouter1 = require("./routes/task1");
const taskRouter2 = require("./routes/task2");
const taskRouter3 = require("./routes/task3");
const taskRouter4 = require("./routes/task4");
const errorRouter = require("./routes/error");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(homeRouter);

// var ch = 1;
// switch (ch) {
//   case 1:
//     app.use(taskRouter.router1);
//     break;
//   case 2:
//     app.use(taskRouter);
//     break;
//   case 3:
//     app.use(taskRouter);
//     break;
//   case 4:
//     app.use(taskRouter);
//     break;
// }
task = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
console.log(task);
switch (task) {
  case 0:
    app.use(taskRouter1);
    break;
  case 1:
    app.use(taskRouter3);
    break;
  case 2:
    app.use(taskRouter3);
    break;
  case 3:
    app.use(taskRouter4);
    break;
}
app.use(errorRouter);
console.log("it has started!");

app.listen(1000);
```

So the thing is its only loading one page at random and after refresh it also loades the same.

Comment: Use a single router. Load the 4 urls into an array.  At run-time, randomly pick one of the URL from array and send it.

Comment: Thanks can you help me with the syntax!

Answer (score 2):

First, load your URLs into an array

```
const arrPaths = []
arrPaths[0] = "/public/task1.html"
arrPaths[1] = "/public/task2.html"
```

Or you can populate it with a filesystem search.It's up to you, however you do it. Just populate the arrPaths that you will randomly choose from

Then we serve setup the express router to respond when GET /random is called

```
router.get("/random", (req, res) => {
```

Now we need t randomly choose a path

```
var chosenPath = arrPaths[Math.floor(Math.random() * (arrPaths.length))];
```

Generates 0 to arrPaths.length-1 and grabs the corresponding arrPaths element

Then we send out the path as the response.

```
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + chosenPath));
})
```

Yours didn't work because you're doing random only once. For this to work, you need to generate the random element EVERY TIME the request was called.

Comment: I was using link to come on this random page so I should use button instead right?

Comment: You can use similar code to compose a button, yes, or if you're using bootstrap, display a link as a button style. But this strictly deals with express.js and URL. OTOH, please clarify what you meant by that.

Comment: I was using <a></a> instead of <button></button>. That's why the page was not refreshing. Maybe! Also how to refresh a route before loading?

Comment: What are you talking about now?

Comment: Bro this helped too! Thank you so muchhhhhh!
I'd to just make a few changes.
I made new diretory utils  and a file called path.js

path.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename);

and then edited router.js with
//This is the root path!
const path = require("path");
const rootDir = require("../utils/path");

and instead of __dirname I used rootDir. headsup and thanks bro again.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use something like this:

```
router.use("/random", (req, res, next) => {
  const task = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir, "views", `task_${task}.html`));
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @TheFlash

Answer (score 0):

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>MAIN</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/random" method="GET">xyz</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Theres a setting that I've done you should use it too.
make a new folder utils, make a file named path.js(this gives you path of the root directory.)
path.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename);
```

So there are two alternatives answers to this question, I'll mention both.

1.
task.js(used as router in express)

```
//This is the root path!
const path = require("path");
const rootDir = require("../utils/path");

//express routing
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// router.use("/random", (req, res, next) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir, "views", "task.html"));
// });

router.use("/random", (req, res, next) => {
  const task = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  console.log(task);
  res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir, "views", `task_${task}.html`));
});

module.exports = router;
```

2. taskie.js

   const arrPaths = [];
   arrPaths[0] = "/views/task_0.html";
   arrPaths[1] = "/views/task_1.html";

   const path = require("path");
   const rootDir = require("../utils/path");

   const express = require("express");
   const router = express.Router();

   router.get("/random", (req, res) => {
     var chosenPath = arrPaths[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrPaths.length)];
     console.log(chosenPath);
     res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir + chosenPath));
   });

   module.exports = router;

Theres also an 3rd alternative which I won't suggest applying. Do ping me if you want to know!